# Consuming XML/SOAP web service in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, soap

I know they removed ActionService out of RoR and opted for RESTful web services. I want to know if Rails is a good choice of a framework for consuming XML/SOAP based web services. Can anyone point out some nice resources/tutorials on how to consume a SOAP based web service in ROR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good step-by-step tutorial for soap4r: [link no longer works]